# How to know which element was clicked when using map function and how to pass that value to another component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
sortedReports.map(item => {

    return (
    <tr key={item.rowNumber}>
        <td>  {item.year}</td>

        <td> {item.month}</td>

        <td> {item.bruto_ukupno}</td>
        <td> {item.neto_plata}</td>
        <td> {item.topli_obrok}</td>

        <td> {item.doprinosi}</td>
        <td> {parseInt(item.ukupno_plata)}</td>

        <td className="table-actions">
            <Link **onClick={}**

                    to={`/reports/details`}>
                <PieChart size="21"/>
            </Link>

        </td>
    </tr>
)});
```

I need to get the  clicked, store its value and pass it to another component where I need to filter employees depending on which reports month was clicked.

THANK YOU SO MUCH :)

Comment: I mean, without knowing the relationship between this component and the other it's hard to say. Assuming the function to filter by month is passed as a prop, the basic answer is `<Link onClick={()=>this.props.filterByMonth(item.month)}.../>`. However, without knowing the context and component hierarchy, we can't say how to filter things by months. That could be a whooooole thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the item as an [extra argument to bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind). List his:

```
sortedReports.map(item => {

    return (
    <tr key={item.rowNumber}>
        <td>  {item.year}</td>

        <td> {item.month}</td>

        <td> {item.bruto_ukupno}</td>
        <td> {item.neto_plata}</td>
        <td> {item.topli_obrok}</td>

        <td> {item.doprinosi}</td>
        <td> {parseInt(item.ukupno_plata)}</td>

        <td className="table-actions">
            <Link onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this,item)}
                to={`/reports/details`}>
                <PieChart size="21"/>
            </Link>

        </td>
    </tr>
)});
```

And then handleClick might look like this:

```
handleClick(item) {
    // Do what you want on click
}
```

I'm binding the entire selected object here, but you could bind just the `item.rowNumber` if that makes the code cleaner elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you @smee so much.
I'm not trying to be rude now, but what would be a great way to pass THAT value from this Reports component to another component ReportsDetails so I can do additional filtering.

State, params, something else?

You already helped so much. Cheers.

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49629053/whats-the-easiest-way-to-pass-a-single-value-between-2-react-components)

Comment: You're welcome! In React, you generally pass things up or down (not sideways), so either (a) pass it down to the props of a subcomponent in render() or (b) pass it up to a parent by calling one of your own props (something like `this.props.onSelectItem(item)`). You might find my earlier answer on state management (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49583761/state-management-in-reactjs/49588360#49588360) helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I would utilize currying to create functions "bound" (but not in the .bind sense) to the value of that item. 
i.e.

```
// as a class method
const createClickHandler = (itemValue) => e => {
   //...doStuff
};
```

Then utilize it by passing the item value when mapping.

```
<Link onClick={this.createClickHandler(item)}
      to={`/reports/details`}>
      <PieChart size="21"/>
</Link>
```